# AngularJS Load Local Data Timing Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I know I have a timing issue here because every once and awhile the view renders correctly with the data populated in my select tag. I believe I have set up my promise then functions incorrectly.

I'm attempting to load a "States" select tag with content loaded from a local JSON object.

AngularJS code

```
var app = angular.module('AAE', []);

app.service('userService', ['$http', function($http) {

    var states = ''; // <-- Focus

    return{
        getStates: function() { // <-- Focus
            return states;
        },
        loadStates: function() { // <-- Focus
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'content/states.json'
                //,async: false
            }).then(function(result) {
                console.log(result.data)
                states = result.data;
            });
        }
    };
}]);

app.controller('EnrollmentController', ['$scope', 'userService', function($scope, userService) { //Dependencies and Constructor function.
    $scope.userService = userService;
    $scope.states = []; // <-- Focus

        userService.loadStates().then(function() { // <-- Focus
            $scope.states = userService.getStates();
            $scope.state = $scope.states[0];

        });
    }
}]);
```

The $scope.states array is populated with the JSON content when inspected at runtime. So I know loadStates() and getStates() are working to some degree, just a timing issue I think...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try with setting $scope.states = result.data in controller also?

Comment: That was a miss type. result actually had no value there. I removed it from the code

Comment: Seems like load states is not returning a promise (since it has its own .then clause as opposed to returning the $http). So the then clause in your controller will get run immediately, which would set the $scope.states and $scope.state to blank values. The service could still be run correctly, but the values are being assigned before it can complete its asynch call.